# Duplicate symbol errors when running go run main.go when using Kafka with librdkafka

Tags: go, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

**The problem**

When I issue a `go run main.go` I get many *duplicate symbol* errors like

```
duplicate symbol __cgo_c9759b266284_Cfunc_rd_kafka_produce_batch in:
    /var/folders/9x/wkfpz7ds6h973089xymk9_mc0000gn/T/go-link-426232578/000015.o
    /var/folders/9x/wkfpz7ds6h973089xymk9_mc0000gn/T/go-link-426232578/000032.o
duplicate symbol __cgo_c9759b266284_Cfunc_do_produce in:
    /var/folders/9x/wkfpz7ds6h973089xymk9_mc0000gn/T/go-link-426232578/000015.o
    /var/folders/9x/wkfpz7ds6h973089xymk9_mc0000gn/T/go-link-426232578/000032.o
duplicate symbol _do_produce in:
    /var/folders/9x/wkfpz7ds6h973089xymk9_mc0000gn/T/go-link-426232578/000015.o
    /var/folders/9x/wkfpz7ds6h973089xymk9_mc0000gn/T/go-link-426232578/000032.o
ld: 74 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

**The context**

My main package imports an external package (owned by myself, but hosted as an external package). Both the main package and this other package import a Kafka package ([github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go)). This Kafka package requires me to have C libraries installed ([librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka)). These C libraries are included when Go compiles the program so that everything works nicely.

**What I think goes wrong**

I think that because both my main package and my external package import the Kafka library, Go thinks it needs to include the C libraries twice. I don't know much about the internals - maybe it does - but it would be nice if it would detect that the libraries have already been included so that this duplicate symbols error  doesn't happen.

**Why I think this**

I don't get any errors if I copy the external package to inside my main package and use it form there instead of importing the external package.

Anyone familiar with this problem and have a fix/workaround?